# EdgesHelper loses its mesh when scene is rotated

Tags: three.js

I've drawn a mesh with a edgeshelper.
When I rotate the scene using the mouse, the edges seems to react twice as fast the mesh.
The result is that the edges don't "fit" around the mesh anymore when the scene is rotated.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
<html>
  <body onmousemove="bmousemove(event);">
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var prevX = 0, prevY = 0;
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1,10000);
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 20, 40, 1, 1, 1 );
      material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
      object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

      edges = new THREE.EdgesHelper( object, 0xffffff );

      camera.position.z = 100;

      scene.add( object );
      scene.add( edges );
      render();

      function render()
      {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      function bmousemove(e)
      {
        if (prevX == 0) 
        {
          prevX = e.clientX;
          prevY = e.clientY;
        }

        scene.rotation.y += (e.clientX - prevX) / 100;
        scene.rotation.x += (e.clientY - prevY) / 100;

        prevX = e.clientX;
        prevY = e.clientY;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using version r71 under Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a consequence of how `EdgesHelper`(and some of the other helpers) have been implemented.

If you want to use `EdgesHelper`, you have to adhere to two rules:

1. `EdgesHelper` must be added to the scene, directly.
2. The `scene` can't have a transform applied (for example, be rotated).

Consequently, you will have to rotate the mesh, instead.

three.js r.71